# Usage of ".. , and .." vs ".. and ... "

Tags: commas, lists

I have noticed in that in cases when listing certain things, the following convention is used

> a, b, c, d and e

But I have also seen some cases where a comma is used before the *and*:

> a, b, c, d, and e

Is there a specific usage case where such a convention comes to play?